# create function that support GET,POST and Command line arguments

Tags: php, function

I have a following class file. When `valid_orginfo()` function call, it checks that incoming data is command line argument or not. then `insert_contact($b)` function is call. where i pass array as parameter(here `$b`).

What i am trying to do is make my function independent of data(means whatever it is GET,POST or command line argument). I don't want to changes in my function. but make one common solution that support every type of incoming data(POST or command line argument). Following class is working(test with `$_POST`),but i am not satisfied with it.

so what can i do so function became independent?
Your suggestion to improve this type of things.
Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
class validation
{   
    function valid_orginfo()
    {
        $a = array();
        if(isset($argv)) {
            $b = $argv;
        }else {
            $b = $_POST;
        }
        extract($b);
        if($org_name!="" and $add!="")
        {
            $this->insert_contact($b);
        }
    }

    function insert_contact($b)
    {
        global $mysqli;
        extract($b);

        $query = "INSERT INTO `personal`(`first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES ('$sfname', '$slname')";

        $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error);
        return $mysqli->insert_id;
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fake $_GET and $_POST if it is called from the command line:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"])) {
    parse_str($argv[1], $_GET);
    parse_str($argv[1], $_POST);
}
```

And call like: `php script.php 'argument1=x&argument2=y'`

Comment: i am trying to know is my function is independent or not in any type of  case? shoud it work in all cases?